# Add condition comment in JavaScript

Tags: html, email, vml

I have an issue rendering a rounded button for my emails in Outlook. I want to give `VML` a try.

```
<!--[if mso]>
<v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://www.EXAMPLE.com/" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:300px;" arcsize="10%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#d62828">
    <w:anchorlock/>
    <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;">
        Button Text Here!
    </center>
</v:roundrect>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !mso]> <!-->
```

My email is generated in JavaScript. How can I create conditional comments in JavaScript ?

Edit 1: 
Using `document.createComment`:

`var c = document.createComment("My personal comments");`

doesn't seem to be helpful as it adds such comment:

`<!--My personal comments-->`

While there are `if`s, `endif`, etc. in the comment. How can I accomplish adding these conditions to the comment ?

Comment: Where is the part of your JavaScript code where you would need the conditional comment? There are no conditional comments in JavaScript, but you can use if/else statements. I suppose you rather mean you'd like to generate the conditional comments in the email markup via JavaScript - but it's not clear what you have tried and why it failed. You can just generate the comments like you generate the rest of the html markup.

Comment: I updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Document.createComment()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createComment) to create a comment node then just append it to a dom node.

```js
//make a comment
var comment = document.createComment("I am a generated comment");
//append it to an element
document.querySelector("html").append(comment);
```

So in your case...

```
var comment = document.createComment('[if mso]> <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://www.EXAMPLE.com/" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:300px;" arcsize="10%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#d62828"> <w:anchorlock/> <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:16px;f‌​‌​ont-weight:bold;"> Button Text Here! </center></v:roundrect><![endif]'); 
document.querySelector("html").append(comment);
```

...should do the trick.

Note that whilst the [Conditional Comments](https://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) might look like 2 special comments with some html in between it's actually just one regular HTML comment.

Comment: how do you create `<![endif]-->` ?

Comment: Presumably that is part of the full comment itself. eg: `[if mso]>
<v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://www.EXAMPLE.com/" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:300px;" arcsize="10%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#d62828">
    <w:anchorlock/>    <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;">        Button Text Here!    </center></v:roundrect><![endif]`

Comment: It wont work in the Snippet because its sandboxed but open up your browser console and type`var comment = document.createComment('[if mso]> <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://www.EXAMPLE.com/" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:300px;" arcsize="10%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#d62828"> <w:anchorlock/> <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:16px;f‌​ont-weight:bold;"> Button Text Here! </center></v:roundrect><![endif]'); document.querySelector("html").append(comment);` then inspect the src

Comment: but you can have `<![endif]-->` as a separate piece of comment after some html documents. Look at the last line of the code I posted, it says if it is not `mso`, use some regular html tags, and then comes the `<![endif]-->`. How do you want to add `endif` ?

Comment: @arian My last comment shows you how to include the `endif`. It's ALL part of the html comment - that's how the conditional comments work. It's a regular/standards comment with messed up MS specific formatting inside it. Old IE / Outlook read these HTML comments, recognise the `MSO` crap in there and parse the comment as if it was some form of instruction. Whereas a normal browser sees it for what it is: just a html comment. See https://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html